# Copy contents of multiple bitmap to one without scaling

Tags: android

I have 2 bitmaps. I want to copy some content from bitmap 1 and some content of bitmap 2 and copy to a bigger bitmap. When i try to do that the smaller bitmap1 gets stretched in the larger bitmap. Is there a way to copy the contents using scaling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your target bitmap, create a `Canvas` for it, then call `Canvas.drawBitmap` to copy the bitmaps onto your larger bitmap.